# Power BI Looping: For/While Loop

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I'm trying to do a simple loop in Power BI Dax, but I'm unable to get this done.

How or can this simple for loop be done in Dax/M Query:

```
> For(i=1,i<=n,i++) 
> print("Week " & i)
```

Essentially what I'm trying to achieve is to get a list of Weeks from 1 to n based on a condition. I'm able to achieve this with if but just wondering if there is a better way to solve this.

Output Desired:

```
Week 1
Week 2
.
Week n
```

Comment: You mean you want to generate a new, single-column table with those entries?

Comment: You can first generate a list from 1..N and the expand the list to row. Finally you can produce values like Week 1, Week 2... Week N based on values from the list.

Comment: @JosWoolley Yes, that's what I wanted. I was able to achieve it though, sorry for the late response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a **List** of weeks from `1 to n`, in the format of `Week 1`, in M code, simply:

```
listOfWeeks= List.Transform({1..n}, each "Week " & Text.From(_))
```